# Repair spark plug wires instead of replace?

Tags: honda, wiring, odyssey

Shakes and misfires on 2004 Honda odyssey: I've just replaced spark plugs, a few faulty coils (had oil in them) and the front-side o-ring and gaskets. I don't want to spend more money. All DIY.

I had this radical idea that if the remaining problem is the wires, I could probably just fix the wire in question rather than replace them right now.

Can that be done? If so, what is suggested? I mean...its a wire.

Comment: They are not made to  be repaired, long ago they were made with wire, but not since the 1960's.........more detail here....https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/r/advice/car-maintenance/wired-up-the-fundamentals-of-spark-plug-wiring

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're saying you want to fix the spark plug wires? If so, your Odyssey doesn't have spark plug wires, but comes with a "coil on" ignition system. If you are saying you have a wiring situation, where the wires going to the coils are messed up, then there's no issue there. Just ensure you keep the wires going to the right places and make the connections clean and secure, then there should be no issues.

Comment: Oh ok! I thought the wires leading to the spark plug coils were the traditional spark plug wires -- but the coils are a whole different animal? In that case perhaps I have to replace the correct coil.

Comment: @LeoBlanchette - Do you have any codes showing? If so, what are they ... these can help you immensely to know which coil might be an issue.